# Bash command with a shell script variable which itself as a parameter with spaces

Tags: bash, parameters

Trying to do imbricated escape and that doesn't work obviously.
My parameter with space is `customer` and its value is `NAME WITH SPACE`.

```
chroot /sites/FOLDER1 /bin/su FOLDER2 -c "/data/batch/myScript.sh -v -g -action params -customer NAME WITH SPACE"
```

I'm getting:

> Error : Unknown parameter WITH

I read a few threads on the subjects but can't make out a solution :
https://superuser.com/questions/360966/how-do-i-use-a-bash-variable-string-containing-quotes-in-a-command
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Tried with single and double quote, with storing the param in a variable etc but no dice.

If I use

```
chroot /sites/FOLDER1 /bin/su FOLDER2 -c '/data/batch/myScript.sh -v -g -action params -customer 'NAME WITH SPACE''
```

It works a little better as I do not get the unknown parameter but it only takes NAME as parameter and ignore what is after the space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`su -c "script-text"` launches a separate shell interpreter which parses `script-text` as code. Consequently, that text needs to be escaped in an `eval`-safe manner. `printf '%q'` does this for bash (and will be entirely robust if your `/bin/sh` is a symlink to bash).

That is:

```
printf -v cmd '%q ' /data/batch/myScript.sh -v -g -action params -customer "NAME WITH SPACE"
chroot /sites/FOLDER1 /bin/su FOLDER2 -c "$cmd"
```

---

If your `/bin/sh` is *not* provided by bash, then you should consider an alternative implementation generating purely POSIX-compliant output, such as that provided by the Python `pipes.quote()` library function:

```
pyquote() {
  python -c 'import pipes, sys; print " ".join(pipes.quote(a) for a in sys.argv[1:])' "$@"
}

cmd=$(pyquote /data/batch/myScript.sh -v -g -action params -customer "NAME WITH SPACE")
chroot /sites/FOLDER1 /bin/su FOLDER2 -c "$cmd"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still get `Unknown parameter WITH`

Comment: `declare -- cmd="/data/batch/myScript.sh -v -g -action params -customer NAME\\ WITH\\ SPACE "`

Comment: Yes `chroot /sites/FOLDER1 /bin/su FOLDER2 -c "$cmd"`

Comment: To summarize from chat: There was a bug in `myScript.sh`, using `$*` rather than `"$@"` to iterate over arguments; with that fixed, the given solution now functions correctly.